# How to use PDFKit represented view with binding in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, pdfkit

I'm exploring PDFKit with swiftUI. Here is my sample code to select a pdf file on macOS (that's work). Show a Quicklook that's works fine too and I want to show a view with pdf content with the help of a PDFKitRepresentedView (see at the end of the code).

PDFKitRepresentedView works fine at first file selection but it doesn't work if I select another file. I thing it's a binding problem but I need help to resolve it.

Thanks...

```
    import SwiftUI
    import UniformTypeIdentifiers
    import QuickLook
    import PDFKit
    
    struct FilePickerView: View {
    @State var filename = ""
    @State var selectFileURL: URL?
    @State var previewURL: URL?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text(filename)
                Button("Select File")
                {
                    let panel = NSOpenPanel()
                    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
                    panel.canChooseDirectories = false
                    panel.allowedContentTypes = [UTType.pdf].compactMap { $0 }
                    if panel.runModal() == .OK {
                        self.selectFileURL = panel.url
                        self.filename = panel.url?.lastPathComponent ?? "<none>"
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
            if let p = selectFileURL {
                PDFKitRepresentedView(url: p)
            }
            
            Button("Preview") {
                previewURL = selectFileURL
            }.quickLookPreview($previewURL)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FilePickerView()
    }
}

struct PDFKitRepresentedView: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    var url : URL
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> PDFView {
        let pdfView = PDFView()
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url:url)
        return pdfView
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: PDFView, context: Context) {  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you are setting the document (and thus the URL) of the `PDFView` inside `makeNSView`, which only gets called *once* when the `View` is created. So, if the `url` parameter updates, nothing will ever change, since the `View` is already created.

You could solve this by using `updateNSView` to update the `document` parameter of the `View`, but if you ever added another parameter, you would risk updating the `document` when that *other* parameter changed as well.

I think this is a reasonable candidate for adding an explicit `id` to the `PDFKitRepresentedView` -- whenever the `id` changes, `makeNSView` will get called again since it will be a *new* `View`.

```
PDFKitRepresentedView(url: p)
  .id(p)
```